# Is my C1/D visa valid for transit in the US, if I want to go on a vacation to Mexico?

Tags: visas

I am a crew member in a cruise ship. After my contract I would like to go to Mexico for vacation. But the flight that I will take will have a layover in the US (LAX). I would like to know if my C1/D visa is ok for that or whether I should get another type of visa?

Answer (score 2):

The C-1 nonimmigrant status is for those in transit to another country.  Your visa allows you to enter the US in C-1 status, so yes, you can use that visa for your trip.

The fact that your visa also allows you to enter in D status is not relevant for this trip, but it certainly doesn't prevent you from using the visa for a simple transit.