# Can I go Mexico as a tourist on a C1D visa?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, mexico

I'm from India and working on a ship. I will sign off in San Francisco and from there I wanted to go for vacation to Mexico, but I don't have a visa. Can I go on a C1D visa to Mexico? It will expire in 2020. Please help me.

Comment: The [official government website](https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/) doesn't specify any particular type of visa. But it does say that you don't need a visa if you are traveling as a crewmember (but you probably knew this already).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is my C1/D visa valid for transit in the US, if I want to go on a vacation to Mexico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108854/is-my-c1-d-visa-valid-for-transit-in-the-us-if-i-want-to-go-on-a-vacation-to-me) and [Does a C1 US transit visa allow entry and travel (tourist) in Mexico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111077/does-a-c1-us-transit-visa-allow-entry-and-travel-tourist-in-mexico)